# Can't call Kotlin's extension property from java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Android Studio 3.4

Here my kotlin class:

```
open class DefaultRestClientCallback<T> : Callback<T> {

    val Response<*>.errorResponse: ErrorResponse
        get() = ErrorUtils.parseError(this)



    override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
```

as you can see here I has property extension:

```
errorResponse
```

From another Kotlin class (Test.kt) I call this like this:

```
class Test {


    fun test() {
        TransportService.login("email",
            "pass", object : DefaultRestClientCallback<JsonElement>() {

                override fun onTangoResponse(response: Response<*>) {
                    val isSuccessful = response.isSuccessful
                    if (isSuccessful) { // code >= 200 && code < 300;
                    } else {
                        val errorResponse = response.errorResponse
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Nice it's work fine.

Now I need to call extension property from java file (**which I'm not able to convert to Kotlin for now**).
I try this:

```
TransportService.login("email", "pass", new DefaultRestClientCallback<JsonElement>() {

    @Override
    public void onTangoResponse(@NotNull Response<?> response) {
        boolean isSuccessful = response.isSuccessful();
        if (isSuccessful) { // code >= 200 && code < 300;
        } else {
            ErrorResponse errorResponse = response.errorResponse();
        }
    }
});
```

}

But I get compile error in this line:

```
 ErrorResponse errorResponse = response.errorResponse();
```

error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'errorResponse()'
```

Comment: Did you try calling it without parenthesis? like `response.errorResponse`

Comment: @SaeedEntezari Yes, but get same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin compiles extension properties into static methods. Here's an example extending the `String` class in a file called `StringUtils.kt`:

```
val String.greeting
  get() = "hello $this"
```

So a very simple method that when called in kotlin like `"fred".greeting` will return `hello fred`.

If you check the kotlin byte code and decompile it in the IDE, you can see that the result is something similar to:

```
public final class StringUtilsKt {
 @NotNull
 public static final String getGreeting(@NotNull String $this$greeting) {
  Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull($this$greeting, "$this$greeting");
  return "hello " + $this$greeting;
 }
}
```

A static method in a class `StringUtilsKt`. This means you can simply call this from java like `StringUtilsKt.getGreeting("fred")` and it will result in the same output.

PS: This is very similar to extension functions. They are also compiled into static methods, but the name usually doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

After decompile Kotlin's byte code I get this:

```
   @NotNull
   public final ErrorResponse getErrorResponse(@NotNull Response $this$errorResponse) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull($this$errorResponse, "$this$errorResponse");
      ErrorResponse var10000 = ErrorUtils.parseError($this$errorResponse);
      Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(var10000, "ErrorUtils.parseError(this)");
      return var10000;
   }
```

so from Java I can call like this:

```
@Override
    public void onTangoResponse(@NotNull Response<?> response) {
        boolean isSuccessful = response.isSuccessful();
        if (isSuccessful) { // code >= 200 && code < 300;
        } else {
            ErrorResponse errorResponse = getErrorResponse(response);
        }
}
```